# How to supress CLI output when running Newman with node.js

Tags: postman, newman

How do I specify the below Newman Reporter options, which are normally done via the command line like this:

`newman run .\API-Common.postman_collection.json 44321 --reporter-cli-no-failures --reporter-cli-no-summary --reporter-cli-no-assertions --reporter-cli-no-success-assertions`

Using the API like this:

```
newman.run({
collection,
environment,
globals,
reporters: ['cli'],
reporter: {
    cli: {
        ???
    }
},
insecure: 'true'
}, process.exit);
```

The newman API reference doesn't seem to indicate how this is done:
[Newman API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#api-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newman.run({
collection,
environment,
globals,
reporters: ['cli'],
reporter: {
    cli: {
        'noSummary': true
    }
},
insecure: 'true'
}, process.exit);
```

just pass it without reporter-reortername

Comment: I think it's `noFailures` when using Newman in a script like that. The names slightly change.

Comment: @DannyDainton yes Thank you Danny , is it documented anywhere :D

Comment: I don't think it's on the readme, I was looking at the code 

Comment: I can confirm its camelCase format - it works :)